# React Native Firestore: How do I listen for database changes at the same time as using the .where() query?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have made a FlatList that gets populated from a firestore database. I can currently do all the CRUD operations, but when I edit an entry, it doesn't change in the FlatList. It does change in the firestore database.

I suspect it's because I'm not using .onSnapshot(). My problem is that I need to filter the data using .where() and I haven't been able to find out how to combine the two operations.

My code looks like this:

```
  export const Coach = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
  const [workoutIds, setWorkoutIds] = useState([]);
  const [workouts, setWorkouts] = useState([]);
  const userRef = firestore().collection('Users');
  const workoutRef = firestore().collection('Workouts');

  // Setting the user state
  auth().onAuthStateChanged(userInstance => {
    if (userInstance) {
      setUser(userInstance);
    }
  });

  // Getting coach id's from firestore - Started out at individual workout id's
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      const subscriber = userRef.doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(userSnap => {
        if (userSnap) {
          setUserName(userSnap.data().Name);
          setWorkoutIds(userSnap.data().Workouts);
        }
      });
      return () => subscriber();
    }
  }, [user]);

  // using the list of coach id's to get workouts
  useEffect(() => {
    if (workoutIds.length != 0) {
      let workoutList = [];
      workoutRef
        .where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', workoutIds)
        .get()
        .then(query => {
          query.forEach(snap => {
            workoutList.push({...snap.data(), key: snap.id});
          });
          setWorkouts(workoutList);
        });
    }
  }, [workoutIds]);
```

The problem should lie in the last useEffect block.

**So how do I get it to listen for changes and update the FlatList, while still using the .where()?**

----------------------------------------- Edit -----------------------------------------

I have tried to add an onSnapshot to my query:

Before:

```
  // using the list of coach id's to get workouts
  useEffect(() => {
    if (workoutIds.length != 0) {
      let workoutList = [];
      workoutRef
        .where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', workoutIds)
        .get()
        .then(query => {
          query.forEach(snap => {
            workoutList.push({...snap.data(), key: snap.id});
          });
          setWorkouts(workoutList);
        });
    }
  }, [workoutIds]);
```

After:

```
  // using the list of coach id's to get workouts
  useEffect(() => {
    if (workoutIds.length != 0) {
      let workoutList = [];
      workoutRef
        .where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', workoutIds)
        .onSnapshot(query => {
          query.forEach(snap => {
            workoutList.push({...snap.data(), key: snap.id});
          });
          setWorkouts(workoutList);
        });
    }
  }, [workoutIds]);
```

It still doesn't update the view straight away and now I get an error about encountering two of the same keys.

Comment: You can call `onSnapshot` on a `Query`. If you're struggling to make that work, please edit your question to show us only the **minimal** code that you can't get to work and show us the exact error you get.

Comment: @FrankVanPuffelen, thanks for your answer. I have tried to do what you said, but I am not sure if I have implemented it right. I still don't get realtime updates to the view.

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see any of the values that you are using for testing (like `workoutIds`), so you will have to tell us what they are (or hard-code their values). You'll also want to set a breakpoint on `query.forEach(snap => {` and run the code in the debugger. When you do that, does it reach that breakpoint? If so, does it also reach it after you change the data?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry, the workoutId is changed whenever I add og delete a workout. I keep track of it in my user database and that id is what is used to render the workouts. I take the id from the user collection and find the corresponding workout in a workout collection.
Using the onSnapshot() as you said, I do go into the forEach(snap => {}) when I update a workout, but I still don't get the view updated. I still get the key error, but I can figure that out afterwards.

Comment: Using:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (workoutIds.length != 0) {
      let workoutList = [];
      workoutRef
        .where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', workoutIds)
        .onSnapshot(query => {
          query.forEach(snap => {
            workoutList.push({...snap.data(), key: snap.id});
          });
          setWorkouts(workoutList);
        });
    }
  }, [workoutIds]);
```
Whenever I edit a workout, all of the workouts are rerendered and I get an error with multiple objects having the same key. But the updated workout is at least displayed.

Comment: Thank you for your help @FrankvanPuffelen. I figured it out :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue I had to add .onSnapshot() to my query for it to listen to changes in the database. On top of that I accidentally put the temporary list that I added objects to, outside the onSnapshot(), so it just kept adding on. After moving the temporary list into the onSnapshot(), it now updates.

Before:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (workoutIds.length != 0) {
      let workoutList = [];
      workoutRef
        .where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', workoutIds)
        .get()
        .then(query => {
          query.forEach(snap => {
            workoutList.push({...snap.data(), key: snap.id});
          });
          setWorkouts(workoutList);
        });
    }
  }, [workoutIds]);
```

After:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (workoutIds.length != 0) {
      workoutRef
        .where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', workoutIds)
        .onSnapshot(query => {
          let workoutList = [];
          query.forEach(snap => {
            workoutList.push({...snap.data(), key: snap.id});
          });
          setWorkouts(workoutList);
        });
    }
  }, [workoutIds]);
```